# Backup Compression in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup, compression

I noticed that simply zipping my backup files reduces the space used by 70%

My idea was to, initially, backup the databases to a local server; then, using Bacula or Cobian (I don't have a budget), compress it and then ship it to our remote SAN.

Did you face similar challenge? If so, how did you overcame it?

Comment: There isn't a question in here. As such, I would reword it, or face getting your question closed.

Answer (score 2):

There are commercial (Redgate for example) and free products that will do this for you as part of the backup.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mssqlcompressed/

Comment: Nice shot, I will give it a try on our test server. Do you use it in production, or know anyone who has first-hand experience with it?

Comment: I don't have any clients using it in production but I use it myself on my laptop and test servers. As standard SQL backup formats are used, with standard compressions libraries injected into the process, it's essentially doing as you were going to do but automated.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to

- SQL Server 2008 Enterprise and higher or
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard and higher

to get it natively.

Or use a 3rd party tools (as per Mark Storey-Smith's answer).

Comment: I would add that backup compression in 2008 comes [only with Enterprise edition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719.aspx). You need 2008 R2 for it to be available in Standard edition.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [RedGate's HyperBac](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-hyperbac/).  It's a few hundred bucks a server and it is well worth the cost.